# Want to plot a graph by avg the values

Tags: vb.net

I want to plot a graph in Vb.net. I have x and y values , x indicates cycles. After every 4 cycles i want to average out all 4 cycles' value and draw a line then in the 5th cycle's graph shows its real graph value and then when cycles reach the 8th cycle then once again average out the value from the starting and plot a straight line. How can I plot this graph?

```
Private _averageValue As Double

Public ReadOnly Property AverageValue() As Double
    Get
        Return _averageValue
    End Get
End Property

Private Sub CalculateAverageValue()
    Try
        Dim sum As Double = 0
        Dim cnt As Integer = 1
        _Reading = ""
        'loop to find the average
        If _SeparatedValues.Count > 0 Then
            For cnt = 1 To _SeparatedValues.Count
                sum = sum + _SeparatedValues(cnt - 1)

                _Reading = _Reading & " " & _SeparatedValues(cnt - 1)

            Next
            _Reading = _Reading.Trim
            _averageValue = sum / (cnt - 1)
        Else
            _averageValue = 0
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: I want to plot a graph in Vb.net. I have x and y values , x indicates cycles . After every 4 cycles i want to avg out all 4 cycles value and draw a line then in 5th cycles graph shows its real graph value and then cycles reach to 8th cycle then once again it avg out the value from the starting and plot a straight line